# Обновление данных из json

Tags: node.js, json, discord

Есть json файл, в нём есть строка "mod":"auto". Есть команда которая меняет это значение. Есть условие:

```
  config1 = require('./config.json'); // Подключаем файл с параметрами и информацией
  let mod = config1.mod; // «Вытаскиваем» из него префикс
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(mod == "auto"){
```

Всё работает отлично, только чтобы бот перечитал значение, нужно его перезапустить. Как это исправить?

Comment: Например сделать парсинг json-файла через `JSON.parse`

Comment: спасибо вам огромное.

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой способ решения, если кому интересно:

```
fs.readFile('./config.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err; // we'll not consider error handling for now
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    mod = obj.mut_mod;
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(mod == "auto"){
```